# Styling Two Elements on Same Line in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to style two elements that need to appear on the same line in my react native app. What I have thus far positions them on the same line - using nested `<Text>` elements - but I'm unclear how to then be able to create some distance between them. For instance, in the example below, I want the icon to be left-aligned, which it is now, but I want the `this.props.client.name` text to be center-aligned. From my understanding margin is ignored in children elements. How can I accomplish this?

```
  <View>
    <Text>
      <Feather name="chevron-left" size={24} 
        onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} 
     />
     <Text>{this.props.client.name}</Text>
   </Text>
 </ View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try styling them using "flex" css properties.

for example if you have:

```
<View>
    <Text>
      <Feather name="chevron-left" size={24} 
        onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} 
     />
     <Text>{this.props.client.name}</Text>
   </Text>
 </ View>
```

TRY

```
<View>
    <Text>
       <View style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", 
         position: "relative", zIndex: 1 }}>
          <Feather name="chevron-left" size={24} 
             onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} 
             style={{position: "absolute", zIndex: 2, left: 0 }}
          />
          <Text>{this.props.client.name}</Text>
      </View>
   </Text>
 </ View>
```

You should now have your Icon on the left  and your text centered.

Read more about Flexbox here. reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: I know you can't use <div> elements but you can use Flex css properties. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: Try wrapping the Icon and the into an another View. View component supports Flexbox. so it should work. I updated my answer so you try it.